# "Not Requested Block Data" synching a parachain node

Tags: parachain, sync

I am facing an issue with syncing new nodes to the bootnodes of my parachain on Kusama. The bootnodes were synced using the following commands:

- For fast sync: `binary --chain <parachainchain> -- --sync=fast`
- For warp sync: `binary --chain <parachainchain> -- --sync=warp`

However, when I try to sync a new node with these bootnodes, I encounter the following log entries:

```
2023-11-29 09:13:37 [Parachain] Report 12D3KooWCEZ635J1LtCSX95vSjk6WzAm6oHdzKdEhiKzLNtiUvpT: -536870912 to -2147483648. Reason: Not requested block data. Banned, disconnecting.
2023-11-29 09:13:37 [Parachain] Report 12D3KooWAkbe8ecKSGUyRjgZwh8DifGiu5oe6s1VbVdBcVmc7mkS: -536870912 to -2147483648. Reason: Not requested block data. Banned, disconnecting.
2023-11-29 09:13:38 [Parachain] Report 12D3KooWQjuPJkXHj25W4QMuemGtcLFHBAiFMMd9snbhqSTB2vn5: -536870912 to -2147483648. Reason: Not requested block data. Banned, disconnecting.
```

As a result, no new node is able to sync with the parachain. I'm seeking advice or insights on the following:

1. What could be causing the "Not requested block data" issue in the context of syncing new nodes with the bootnodes?
2. The numeric values reported in the logs (-536870912 to -2147483648) are confusing. Can someone explain their significance?
3. Are there any known solutions or workarounds to resolve this syncing issue?

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/genesis-sync-and-history-are-archive-nodes-indispensable